# How to access a previous matrix field value

Tags: matrix

I have a case where I need to access a previous matrix field's value (if it exists) in the next matrix loop result.

```
{% for contentBlock in entry.contentBlocks %}
    {% if contentBlock.prev %}
        {% if contentBlock.getPrev().matrixField | length %}
            {{ contentBlock.getPrev().matrixField }}
        {% endif %}
    {% endif 
    ....
{% endfor %}
```

I know that my issue is with `{{ contentBlock.getPrev().matrixField }}` but I am not sure how to access the field value after trying several methods.  I'm sure it's something simple.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turns out, you must use bracketed and not dotted syntax for matrix fields.

```
{% for contentBlock in entry.contentBlocks %}
    {% if contentBlock.prev %}
        {% if contentBlock.prev[matrixField] is defined %}
            {{ contentBlock.prev[matrixField] }}
        {% endif %}
    {% endif 
    ....
{% endfor %}
```

fixed this issue for me :)

Comment: I had to enclose the field handle in quotes otherwise I got a "variable does not exist" erorr `{{ contentBlock.prev['matrixField'] }}`